# There is a way to decide witch cone is getting bigger and smaller?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm getting started with the geometry node and I wonder if there is a way to create some "fade effect" with this node.
I know that with the array modifier, and an empty I can make the cone progressively go from big to small, but there is a way to decide which cone is getting bigger or smaller ?

Thank u

[image]

Comment: did u try scale instances with index?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the *Curve to Points* node, I would take a *Resample Curve* node. This way you can use *Spline Parameter* > *Factor* for the *Scale*. The factor will always be from 0 to 1, no matter how long you make the curve/spiral or which *Length* you set for resampling.

This way you know, the first cone will always be a scale of 0 and the last one full size which you have set in the cone's properties. To modify you can use *Math* nodes to *Multiply* or *Add* something to the factor etc., or to give it a different minimum or maximum size you can plug the factor in a *Map Range* node, a *Color Ramp* or maybe a *Float Curve* node for example. You can also use a *Combine XYZ* node if you do not want to scale the cone uniformly, but maybe the height different from the rest.

With a setup like this you can decide what the minimum and maximum size of the cone should be, and it will not change even if you change the start or end radius of the spiral or how it is resampled.

Basic setup (with a *Multiply* node to set the final scale instead of adjusting the cone values):

[image: basic scaling]

Using a *Map Range* node (in this case increasing the minimum size):

[image: map range node]

A *Float Curve* node for visual editing of the size changes:

[image: float curve]

Or with a *Color Ramp* you can change the size multiple times from start to finish as well:

[image: color ramp]